# CSS on Zend Framework

Tags: php, html, css, zend-framework

I am using Zend Framework to create a website.
I have header, footer, and the usual pages.
I am using a CSS file that is public/css/styles.css

Although, the CSS is not being integrated, instead when running it, it shows this:
Footer.phtml
[image: page]

Layout.phtml
[image: page-main]

example of footer phtml

```
<!-- application/views/scripts/footer.phtml-->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<?php echo $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet($this->baseUrl().'css/styles.css') ?>

<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<?php echo $this->headScript()->appendFile('js/scripts.js') ?>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="foot-container">
(...)
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

layout.phtml

```
<!-- application/layouts/scripts/layout.phtml -->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Frontend Test</title>
<?php echo $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('css/styles.css') ?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<?php echo $this->headScript()->appendFile('js/scripts.js') ?>
<?php echo $this->headLink(); ?>
<?php echo $this->headScript(); ?>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo $this->render('header.phtml') ?>
<?php echo $this->layout()->content ?>
<?php echo $this->render('footer.phtml') ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First and foremost: is the path to your CSS file generated correctly? Just use the code inspector in the browser or use the 'view source' option. Second (and this is a long shot): are you certain that you have saved your CSS file in the right position? It should be somewhere in public.

Comment: I have my CSS in /public/css/styles.css, layout in layouts/scripts/layout.phtml and header/footer in /views/scripts/footer.phtml

All paths seem correct

Comment: This may sound like a silly question but how do you exactly call those pages? Your output looks like you're requesting them as html files and not through the view.

Comment: Could you post the generated HTML source please? Just do a Ctrl+U in your Chrome browser and post everything between the <head> tags. Also, not sure, but I think that you should end your echo statements with semicolons, which you do not appear to be doing consistently.

Comment: Ok. I was messing around the php echo and somehow I fixed it....
Not really sure how though. 
Thank you for all the tips. Especially the ; in the end of statements. I hadn't noticed that ;)

Answer (score 0):

Including a css/js file in zendframework

1.In your layout file /head section

```
<head>
<?php echo $this->headLink() ; ?>
<?php echo $this->headScript() ; ?>
</head>
```

2.In your respective phtml files

```
<?php $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet($this->baseUrl . '/css/yourcss.css'); ?>
<?php  $this->headScript()->appendFile($this->baseUrl . '/js/yourjs.js'); ?>
```

Comment: Did not work. I am updating with more code on the post